# Is there a way to generate unlimited styles rules from a unique element with css? (as if nesting several pseudo-elements)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Just for learning and experimenting, is there any way to generate unlimited css styles stuff from scratch within a unique element without children? Would be as if using pseudo-elements like `::after` and `::before`, but several times at a same selector.

Sadly, I notice that `::after` and `::before` pseudo-elements works like self-closed elements (`input`, `img`, etc), as well, these selectors in css don't support pseudo-elements. Therefore is obvious that pseudo-elements selectors can't nest others pseudo-elements (I hope that i use the right term) for get a purposed effect because they can't contain children...

So, I want to generate styles rules from scratch within unique elements without use auxiliary children (like `<i></i>`, `<span></span>`, `<div></div>`) using only pure css (no javascript).

---

I hope that this little example by using selector with several nested pseudo-elements can represent my goal:

**HTML**

```
<!-- A magnifying glass icon for search bars --> 
<i class="search icon"></i>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Common icon properties */
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1em; height: 1em;
}
/* Search icon initial properties */
.icon.search {
  --stick-color: gray;
}
/* Magnifying glass circle 
generated by using css shapes */
.icon.search::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: .15em; left: .05em;
  width: .5em; height: .5em;
  border: 0.15em solid;
  border-color: var(--stick-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
/* Magnifying glass stick 
generated by using css borders */
.icon.search::after::after {  /* It will not work because */
  content: " ";               /* selectors can't support  */
  position: absolute;         /* several ::after elements */
  top: .9em; left: .55em;
  width: .6em; height: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-bottom: .1em solid var(--stick-color);
  border-top: .1em solid var(--stick-color);
  border-radius: 0 .2em .2em 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* Another issue is that, if it could work, it inherit 
     relative current position of first pseudo-element, 
     getting a unexpected behavior.                      */
}
```

**Result:** it should display a simple gray search icon if nested pseudo-elements could be nested.

---

For get work this example i should create a auxiliary element (like a `span` or whatever) and then next apply the generated stick shape style to the `span` element and `span::after` pseudo-element:

**HTML**

```
<!-- A span element added for generate stick shape within it --> 
<i class="search icon"><span></span></i>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Common icon properties */
.icon {
  . . .
}
/* Search icon initial properties */
.icon.search {
  . . .
}
/* Magnifying glass circle 
generated by using css shapes */
.icon.search::after {
  . . .
}
/* Magnifying glass stick 
generated by using css borders */
.icon.search > span {    /* This a auxiliary     */
  display: inline-block; /* element for generate */
  position: absolute;    /* the stick.           */
}
.icon.search > span::after {
  /* previous .icon.search::after::after stuff here */
}
```

**Result:* It works pretty well, but i'm forcing to use a element within which isn't the goal, [you can see it on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alfonsosuarezg/0632gauz/).

---

**Note: I know that i can use javascript for straight forward stuff generation.**

**Othe Note:** Sorry if my english isn't understandable.

Comment: short answer: you cannot generate as many nested element as you want with CSS. Long answer: If you make your question more specific on what you are trying to achieve then it can be possible to do it without the need of a lot of elements. We can easily create a search icon using only one element.

Comment: I'm making a experimental 2D animation engine based on web technologies (for learning), i want to do complex styles rulesets without the need of append another elements within the target element. Search icon example was a little demonstration of one level depth of generation stuff from scratch using graphics from css. My target is get into deeply and generate unlimited graphics from a element (applying from css styles).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to build ["Web Components"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) from scratch. There are a variety of Javascript frameworks/libraries with explicit features for building components. For example, here are the [docs on Vue components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html).

These frameworks were developed in part because it's difficult to manage components using pure HTML, CSS, and JS. Unlike psuedo-elements, most JS components support nesting, iteration, etc. I imagine it's extremely difficult (maybe impossible) to develop very sophisticated components with only HTML and CSS.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a bit confused, but I have two assumptions:

1. you would like to apply `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements to all i tags and their children

Assuming the following markup:

```html
<i><span></span></i>
<div><p></p></div>
<p><span></span></p>
```

`::before` and `::after` for i elements and their children

```css
/* to I element and its children */
i::before, i *::before,
i::after, i *::after {
    content: "";
}
```

Output:

[image]

`::before` and `::after` for all elements

```css
/* To all elements on the page */
*::before,
*::after {
    content: "";
}
```

Output:

[image]

2. You would like to generate CSS styles for elements as if you'd work with a scripting language:

For that you can use SASS: [Sass Basics](https://sass-lang.com/guide#example-3-scss)